# How to differentiate folders from files in storage.getFiles() response?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

This is what I have in my bucket:

```
images/
  image1.jpeg
```

I'm using the `storage.bucket().getFiles()` method:

```
const images = await storage.bucket().getFiles({ prefix: 'images' });
console.log(images);
```

And this is the response I'm getting:

- You can see that I get 2 items.
- 1 for the `images` folder itself
- And 1 for the actual `image1.jpeg` file

```
[
  [
    File {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      metadata: [Object],
      baseUrl: '/o',
      parent: [Bucket],
      id: 'images%2F',
      createMethod: undefined,
      methods: [Object],
      interceptors: [],
      projectId: undefined,
      create: undefined,
      bucket: [Bucket],
      storage: [Storage],
      kmsKeyName: undefined,
      userProject: undefined,
      name: 'images/',
      acl: [Acl],
      instanceRetryValue: true,
      instancePreconditionOpts: undefined,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    File {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      metadata: [Object],
      baseUrl: '/o',
      parent: [Bucket],
      id: 'images%2Fimage1.jpeg',
      createMethod: undefined,
      methods: [Object],
      interceptors: [],
      projectId: undefined,
      create: undefined,
      bucket: [Bucket],
      storage: [Storage],
      kmsKeyName: undefined,
      userProject: undefined,
      name: 'images/image1.jpeg',
      acl: [Acl],
      instanceRetryValue: true,
      instancePreconditionOpts: undefined,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }
  ]
]
```

I would like to loop over the files in `images[0]` and be able to differentiate the folder from the files. How can I do it?

Comment: That doesn't seem right. Do you have any other directories/files with names starting with `images`? Can you also share a screenshot of the files in the bucket involved in the question.

Comment: I have added a comment below.please check

Answer (score -1):

Tried this on live data in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list)

with `{ prefix: 'images' }` the entire bucket under the prefix is returned.

with `{ prefix: 'images/' }`  the entire folder under the prefix is returned.

with  `{ prefix: 'images/image'}` restrict the results to only the "files" in the given "folder"

If you want to list only files in the given folder try changing the prefix like this:

```
const images = await storage.bucket().getFiles({ prefix: 'images/image' });
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. `image1.jpeg` was just an example. Not all of my files start with `image`.

Comment: @cbdeveloper okay you can give any filename that you want to return with that prefix `{ prefix: 'foldername/filename'}`.

Comment: The file names are auto generated (random UUIDs) and I need to search for all of them.

Comment: I think you have only two options then ,rename the files with the same prefix which you want to return or return `{ prefix: 'foldername/' }`  it will return the folder itself

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking. It's not about `how do we make it only return files`, it's more of `when we asked for BOTH files and folders, how can we tell that one is a folder and another is a file`